# On select change always display first disabled option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple select with several options:

```
<select id = "actionslist">
    <option id="selectoption" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value = "Remove Plans">Remove Plans</option>
     <option value = "Something else">Something Else</option>
</select>
```

My question is, when I click Remove Plans, my onchange event is kicked off, and I see it in the select window, rather than first disabled selected option Select. 
How can I ALWAYS keep Select in the select window and let user re-pick whatever option they want without actually "selecting" it and showing in the select window.

```
 $('#actionslist').bind("change", function () {
            var item = $(this).val();
            if (item === "Remove Plans")
            {
              //do something
            }
        });
```

Again, I want "Select" always to show, NOT the option that user clicks on. Yet, I don't want Select to be one of the options that user can click on.

idea here is to make sure that onchange event is kicked in at all times, even if user keeps selecting same option over and over.

ThankS!

Comment: It's not what `<select>` was built to do. You can only achieve what you want by creating a fake dropdown box.

Comment: Hmm.. how? :)
I am just wondering what would be the best approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just reset it during the on change event. `$(this).prop('selectedIndex',0)`. However, you would now have to reference on the value (basically storing it in a variable). The select element will now have the original value.

```js
$( "#actionslist" ).bind( "change", function() {
  
  console.log(this.value)
  
  if (this.value === "Remove Plans") {
     //do something
  }

  $(this).prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "actionslist">
    <option id="selectoption" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value = "Remove Plans">Remove Plans</option>
     <option value = "Something else">Something Else</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily – simple add `this.selectedIndex = 0;` at the end of your change function

```js
$('#actionslist').bind("change", function () {
    var item = $(this).val();
    console.log(item)
    if (item === "Remove Plans")
    {
      //do something
    }
    this.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "actionslist">
    <option id="selectoption" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value = "Remove Plans">Remove Plans</option>
     <option value = "Something else">Something Else</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well creating an unclickable select box that overlay the actual select box is one of the (quick, dirty) solution. You will have to take care to make sure they overlap though:

```js
$('#fakeActionslist').bind("change", function() {
  $('#actionslist').val($(this).val());
  $(this).val('');
  
  alert($('#actionslist').val()); // User's latest choice is saved in $('#actionslist').val()
});
```

```css
.select-container {
  position: relative;
}

#fakeActionslist {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-container">
  <select id="actionslist">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="Remove Plans">Remove Plans</option>
    <option value="Something else">Something Else</option>
  </select>
  <select id="fakeActionslist">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="Remove Plans">Remove Plans</option>
    <option value="Something else">Something Else</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting.. doesn't seem like onchange event is firing at all though when I select the option [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q27HX/37/)

Comment: But of course! You didn't include jQuery in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q27HX/38/

Comment: Yes, silly me.. thanks. Seems like change event still won't be fired though even if  I try click remove plans again. =(

Comment: this is def closer to waht I need.. but my hope was that onchange would now keep firing off anytime I pick remove plans, even if I already picked it once.

Comment: You don't need two selects to achieve this; see my answer

Comment: @KevinJantzer before all that edits - in the beginning - he was saying he want to be able to save the user's choice, but get the "visual" of an unselected select box. It slowly changed to alert the choice user just made somehow...